# Kubernetes can't curl to pod in the node

Tags: kubernetes

I'm new to K8s and just installed by kubespray with this one
https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubespray/.
k8s - v1.20.2.
calico - 3.16.6.
pod-cidr = 10.214.0.0/16.
service-cidr = 10.215.0.1/16.

```
kubectl get pod -o wide
NAME                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP              NODE              NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
web-79d88c97d6-lk2sq    1/1     Running   0          31h   10.214.39.1     dev1   <none>           <none>
web2-5b669f8984-gwfx2   1/1     Running   0          8h    10.214.40.130   dev2   <none>           <none>
```

I can curl to web-79d88c97d6-lk2sq pod in dev2 **but can't in dev1**.
**Is it normal?** If not so how can i fix it?

```
curl -v 10.214.39.1:8080
* About to connect() to 10.214.39.1 port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 10.214.39.1...
* Connection timed out
* Failed connect to 10.214.39.1:8080; Connection timed out
* Closing connection 0
```

```
traceroute 10.214.39.1
traceroute to 10.214.39.1 (10.214.39.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  gateway (10.61.8.1)  7.790 ms  8.173 ms  8.394 ms
 2  10.6.41.10 (10.6.41.10)  0.613 ms 10.6.41.6 (10.6.41.6)  0.505 ms 10.6.41.8 (10.6.41.8)  0.612 ms
 3  10.6.32.150 (10.6.32.150)  0.740 ms 10.6.9.169 (10.6.9.169)  0.962 ms 10.6.32.158 (10.6.32.158)  1.233 ms
 4  10.6.32.178 (10.6.32.178)  0.350 ms 10.6.32.232 (10.6.32.232)  8.849 ms 10.6.32.236 (10.6.32.236)  8.850 ms
 5  172.24.0.172 (172.24.0.172)
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
```

from web-79d88c97d6-lk2sq pod to web2-5b669f8984-gwfx2 pod **curl worked**

Kube-system Pod status

```
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-847f479bc5-k52fm      1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   calico-node-8x5h8                             1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   calico-node-9lhbn                             1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   calico-node-bh9f8                             1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   calico-node-dpxjk                             1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   calico-node-fl5gj                             1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   calico-node-g2qzl                             1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   calico-node-g9x82                             1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   calico-node-pl292                             1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   calico-node-t7kwd                             1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   calico-node-v5s8r                             1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   coredns-847f564ccf-l4qk9                      0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   441        31h
kube-system   dns-autoscaler-b5c786945-pxbwh                0/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-dev10               1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-dev8                1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-dev9                1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-dev10      1/1     Running            0          168m
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-dev8       1/1     Running            0          167m
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-dev9       1/1     Running            0          166m
kube-system   kube-proxy-89cbl                              1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   kube-proxy-8d6tm                              1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   kube-proxy-8qnm9                              1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   kube-proxy-bblxx                              1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   kube-proxy-fshgk                              1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   kube-proxy-j5s6f                              1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   kube-proxy-m8jts                              1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   kube-proxy-r9wqh                              1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   kube-proxy-t4r7g                              1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   kube-proxy-wxs4m                              1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   kube-scheduler-dev10               1/1     Running            0          168m
kube-system   kube-scheduler-dev8                1/1     Running            0          167m
kube-system   kube-scheduler-dev9                1/1     Running            0          166m
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-5f87bdc77d-4j8rp         1/1     Running            408        31h
kube-system   kubernetes-metrics-scraper-64db6db887-k48b6   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   417        31h
kube-system   nginx-proxy-dev1                   1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   nginx-proxy-dev2                   1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   nginx-proxy-dev3                   1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   nginx-proxy-dev4                   1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   nginx-proxy-dev5                   1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   nginx-proxy-dev6                   1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   nginx-proxy-dev7                   1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   nodelocaldns-5plj9                            1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   nodelocaldns-hb6lm                            1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   nodelocaldns-j4wtf                            1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   nodelocaldns-lkj2g                            1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   nodelocaldns-pp4xd                            1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   nodelocaldns-ttvwq                            1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   nodelocaldns-vgnwv                            1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   nodelocaldns-vpfjm                            1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   nodelocaldns-xfzw4                            1/1     Running            0          31h
kube-system   nodelocaldns-zrnfl                            1/1     Running            0          31h
```

```
kubectl get componentstatuses
Warning: v1 ComponentStatus is deprecated in v1.19+
NAME                 STATUS    MESSAGE             ERROR
scheduler            Healthy   ok
controller-manager   Healthy   ok
etcd-1               Healthy   {"health":"true"}
etcd-2               Healthy   {"health":"true"}
etcd-0               Healthy   {"health":"true"}
```

```
kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP           NODE              NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
test-curl-deployment-5cdddb7854-24n82   1/1     Running   0          17s   10.214.223.135   dev4   <none>           <none>
test-curl-deployment-5cdddb7854-jpzwp   1/1     Running   0          17s   10.214.102.6     dev3   <none>           <none>
test-curl-deployment-5cdddb7854-qtr8k   1/1     Running   0          17s   10.214.229.6     dev2   <none>           <none>
web-79d88c97d6-lk2sq                    1/1     Running   0          2d    10.214.39.1      dev5   <none>           <none>
web2-5b669f8984-gwfx2                   1/1     Running   0          25h   10.214.40.130    dev7   <none>           <none>


$ kubectl exec test-curl-deployment-5cdddb7854-24n82 -- curl -m 3 test-curl-deployment-5cdddb7854-jpzwp
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:05 --:--:--     0
curl: (28) Resolving timed out after 3000 milliseconds
command terminated with exit code 28
```

coredns pod log and description

```
Name:                 coredns-847f564ccf-l4qk9
Namespace:            kube-system
Priority:             2000000000
Priority Class Name:  system-cluster-critical
Node:                 dev10/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Start Time:           Wed, 05 Jan 2022 15:29:19 +0900
Labels:               k8s-app=kube-dns
                      pod-template-hash=847f564ccf
Annotations:          cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 10.214.122.1/32
                      cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 10.214.122.1/32
                      seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/pod: runtime/default
Status:               Running
IP:                   10.214.122.1
IPs:
  IP:           10.214.122.1
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/coredns-847f564ccf
Containers:
  coredns:
    Container ID:  docker://91492fa6c6a42b2606fc8ae5edc5c5f188bb4a8175e3a6c5185f8a9dbe30cc5d
    Image:         k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.7.0
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://k8s.gcr.io/coredns@sha256:73ca82b4ce829766d4f1f10947c3a338888f876fbed0540dc849c89ff256e90c
    Ports:         53/UDP, 53/TCP, 9153/TCP
    Host Ports:    0/UDP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Args:
      -conf
      /etc/coredns/Corefile
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Fri, 07 Jan 2022 16:58:24 +0900
      Finished:     Fri, 07 Jan 2022 17:00:13 +0900
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  687
    Limits:
      memory:  170Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
      memory:     70Mi
    Liveness:     http-get http://:8080/health delay=0s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=10
    Readiness:    http-get http://:8181/ready delay=0s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=10
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /etc/coredns from config-volume (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from coredns-token-hr9ht (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  config-volume:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      coredns
    Optional:  false
  coredns-token-hr9ht:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  coredns-token-hr9ht
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  kubernetes.io/os=linux
Tolerations:     node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane:NoSchedule
                 node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                     From     Message
  ----     ------     ----                    ----     -------
  Warning  BackOff    8m4s (x3447 over 20h)   kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container
  Warning  Unhealthy  3m19s (x2865 over 20h)  kubelet  Liveness probe failed: Get "http://10.214.122.1:8080/health": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

0107 07:59:56.981861       1 trace.go:116] Trace[817455089]: "Reflector ListAndWatch" name:pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:125 (started: 2022-01-07 07:59:26.981164884 +0000 UTC m=+62.651400285) (total time: 30.000649425s):
Trace[817455089]: [30.000649425s] [30.000649425s] END
E0107 07:59:56.981887       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: Get "https://10.215.0.1:443/api/v1/endpoints?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 10.215.0.1:443: i/o timeout
I0107 07:59:57.665238       1 trace.go:116] Trace[1006933274]: "Reflector ListAndWatch" name:pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:125 (started: 2022-01-07 07:59:27.66473076 +0000 UTC m=+63.334966123) (total time: 30.0004649s):
Trace[1006933274]: [30.0004649s] [30.0004649s] END
E0107 07:59:57.665261       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Namespace: Get "https://10.215.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 10.215.0.1:443: i/o timeout
I0107 07:59:57.935685       1 trace.go:116] Trace[629431445]: "Reflector ListAndWatch" name:pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:125 (started: 2022-01-07 07:59:27.935177307 +0000 UTC m=+63.605412681) (total time: 30.000464179s):
Trace[629431445]: [30.000464179s] [30.000464179s] END
E0107 07:59:57.935704       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get "https://10.215.0.1:443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 10.215.0.1:443: i/o timeout
```

Comment: The IP you're curling is a virtual IP internal to Kubernetes. It is not directly accessible to the outside world. You need to expose your service in some way then access it via localhost (or the host machine's IP).

Answer (score 1):

As the curl error message is showing you have a dns issue, not network! curl failed to resolve the pod name, and if you check pods status in kube-system namespace, coredns failed to run and it's in CrashLoopBackOff status.
Check your core dns logs.

Comment: Thanks. @h.bahadorzadeh Yes coredns is in CrashLoopBackOff status. I attached log and description. From the log get API is ended up with i/o timeout. so that I thought that it is network issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hi it is not normal to curl one node and not curling another, even if you think there ip's are different its just the node difference. You can curl via kubectl exec and check whether are you able to curl the service or not

```
kubectl exec pod_name -- curl -m 3 if any service_name_pods_connects_to
```

and you can share the result probably.

Comment: Thanks @Bisshwajit. Do I have to create service for pod to test curl?

Comment: sorry for delay in replying, you can curl in your own pod if it has curl enabled.